# background rails job processing large JSONL files lead to memory issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

We have been having issues processing large JSONL files (opened via URI) on Heroku via background jobs (Sidekiq). We upgraded to 1GB dyno and are still running out of memory (R14). We distilled the issue to the following process (see pseudocode below), which many times processes files that have 100K+ lines.

I don't think it's the `URI.open` that's causing the issue, but rather storing the data in order to process.

- Would using Redis solve this?
- If so, should I use [redis-rails](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails) or something else (the project is Rails 6.1.4)

```
URI.open(url_name).each do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    hash = JSON.parse(line)
    # calculate and store result in in-memory variables
  end
end
output variables to MongoDB using bulk write
```

Comment: Since you already have MongoDB, I'd be tempted to just write your intermediate variables to mongoDB.

Comment: I would download the file then use https://github.com/chef/ffi-yajl to parse it. I've successfully parsed 600MB files (if I remember correctly) and didn't run out of memory.